# to_SQL nan and Null Values, Still getting 'nan' string literal in SQL Table

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to figure out this issue of 'nan' string literals being loaded into the target table and I've exhausted the several solutions I've read on Stack Overflow.

I have data that needs to be all in string format when it is loaded to the target table so that they are stored in varchar format.

Actual_Load is my dataframe that I'm trying to prepare for the load.

```
1) actual_load = actual_load.where(pd.notnull(actual_load), None)
2) actual_load = actual_load.replace({pd.np.nan: None})
3) for each in actual_load.columns:
    actual_load[each] = actual_load[each].apply(lambda v: str(v) if str(v) != 'nan' else None).tolist()
```

This is my to_sql statement:

engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://serverName/databaseName?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes')
conn = engine.connect()
actual_load.to_sql('target_table', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)

Even with solution 3, most values are being loaded with values of "NULL" into the SQL table, but some portion of the column still has 'nan' as a string.

Comment: did you check the meta types for the column, are nullable values allowed?

Comment: Yes, the table design allows NULL values for every column in the table.